# Tinymce Editors Loading Very Slow

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using tinymce v4.5.3 to create multiple editors within Bootstrap modals on some pages. The project is in angular2 and typescript. The problem is tinymce is being created very slow (at least 4-5 seconds) in one modal that shows 3 seperate windows. The editors is running properly in any other modal in any other page. This modal's only difference is that it is in a seperate component, not in the same component with the page. I couldn't manage to run tinymce faster. If you have any ideas why the editors running very slow in the bootstrap modal component, please help me figure it out. I cannot provide a example running code since it is a private project. Thank you.

Comment: Hi i am also facing same issue. Please update here once you find anything